# Replace special characters in two fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, keyup

I have a form to add a field with news title and would like to use this field to add to the title of the url.
I would like to rewrite the title live in another field like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/atmoner/5sPZa/1/

but I would replace the special character (space, interrogation, exclamation ....)
Even if they should be written in plain, it does not bother me, but I do not see how

Exemple:

```
new article,like this !
```

To:

```
new-article-like-this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your jsfiddle, you should write `changed` function in this way:

```
function changed() {
    var v = this.value.replace(/\W+/g, '-')
        .replace(/-+$/, '')
        .replace(/^-+/, '');

    $("#label2").val(v);
}
​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change this:

```
$("#label2").val(this.value);
```

to this:

```
var value = this.value;
value = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-');  // special char(s) -> hyphen
value = value.replace(/^-|-$/g, ''); // remove leading/trailing hyphen
$("#label2").val(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.. It is just a starting point.. customize it as you need.

```
$("#label1").bind("keyup", changed).bind("change", changed);

function changed() {
    $("#label2").val(this.value
         .replace(/\s|,/g, '_')       /* replace with _ */
         .replace(/!/g, ''));         /* simply remove */
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5sPZa/3/